# How do I send text messages from an iMac OSX El Capitan to an Android phone?

Tags: macos, sms, android

The recipient is not registered on iMessage, which leads me to believe he is not on an iMac.  I have received txts from him on my Android and I have his phone number.  Is there a way to do it on OS X without purchasing additional software?

Comment: Are you looking how to use iCcloud to get OS X to send SMS via iPhone or is the android device looking to emulate / spoof an iPhone to get iCloud to message via android?

Comment: An iPhone that has been linked to a Mac can send both iMessages and SMS directly from Messages.app on the Mac. This is not possible with an Android phone, at least not without third-party software.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage uses a connected iPhone to send text messages from your Mac to anyone, including Android. Unfortunately you're using an Android phone so you're going to need a third party app.